# Slickcarousel has no rendering definition

Tags: rendering, typo3, slick.js

I have a problem with the slick-carousel Typo3-Extension.

At the frontend, this error message shows up:

> ERROR! Content Element type "slickcarousel" has no rendering definition!

I searched a long time for this, but didn't find a solution.

The static template **is included** in the root page.

Comment: Could you add your HTML and all the JS you're using to add any DOM elements and then initialize Slick? A working jsfiddle would be most useful

Comment: Have you checked Typoscript Object Browser, tt_content > slickcarousel

Comment: Have you checked that? Have you tried to insert the slickcarousel setup on the last position? I think you override something.